# Why does indexing a string in c++ gives a warning of implicit conversion?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, implicit-conversion

i have two strings of the same length and i need to see if they are the same string, i know there is a built in way to do just that, and also there operator overloading to do just that however i wanted to do this way. Which is by checking and see if `s1[i]==s2[2]` however when i do it i get the following warning:

```
implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'std::basic_string<char,
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long long')
```

Here is what i do to get this warning:

```
for (auto i=0;i<word.size();i++)
    {
         if(alphabets[i]==word[i])
            counter++;
    }
```

Comment: Try `auto i=0u`. The warning message is pretty clear IMO.

Comment: Or `for (decltype(word.size()) i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i)` or `for (size_t i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i)`

Answer (score 0):

`auto i = 0` yields `i` to be defined as a `int`.
Use `std::size_t i = 0` instead will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

String indices are defined as type `size_t` which is defined as being unsigned. Since your `i` is of type `int` which is signed, there has to be an implicit type conversion to convert between signed and unsigned types. The compiler warns about these because of the wierdness that occurs if you convert negative numbers in this manner.